# PHP : Asking about the way preg_match works

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm working on adding values into a template and have a problem.

Here is my template

```
TIME : |time,hour|:|time,min|:|time,sec| <br />
ADDING BLOCK 'TIME' ...<br />
<i>|template,tibcoreapps,main|</i><br />
```

The characters `|` is used for seperating blocks of data. When I tried to get block `|template,tibcoreapps,main|` using `preg_match` , it didn't work with my code :

```
preg_match("/(.*)|template,tibcoreapps,(.*)|(.*)/",$templateContent,$result);

var_dump($result);
```

And result is

```
array (size=2)
0 => string 'TIME : |time,hour|:|time,min|:|time,sec| <br />  (length=48)
1 => string 'TIME : |time,hour|:|time,min|:|time,sec| <br />  (length=48)
```

I tried searching around the internet but can't get exactly how `preg_match` works. I used to think it gets all matched strings if I assign `$result` ( the third parameter ) . But even when I try to get a block which starting with `template,tibcoreapps,`, it returns other blocks or the first blocks it gets. Please explain me the way `preg_match` works.

Thank you for any helps.

Comment: This is documentation: http://php.net/preg_match The | has a special meaning... This can cause problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `|` has special meaning in regular expressions, you need to escape it.

```
preg_match("/(.*)\|template,tibcoreapps,(.*)\|(.*)/",$templateContent,$result);
```

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, you should read the tutorial at [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info).

Comment: Thank you so much . But when I add one more similar block as the one before , still only one result . My template is now `TIME : |time,hour|:|time,min|:|time,sec| <br />
ADDING BLOCK 'TIME' ...<br />
<i>|template,tibcoreapps,main|</i><br />
<i>|template,tibcoreapps,index|</i><br />` . And result is still `array (size=4)
  0 => string '<i>|template,tibcoreapps,main|</i><br />
' (length=41)
  1 => string '<i>' (length=3)
  2 => string 'main' (length=4)
  3 => string '</i><br />
' (length=11)`